# Is "to have an albatross around one's neck" in common modern usage?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, ielts

I heard it on the BBC a few days ago - "[to have an albatross around one's neck](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/albatross+around+neck)".

**Questions**

- Is it in current usage?
- Can I use it in formal contexts?

I want to use it in the speaking part of my IELTS exam (I should use idioms as well) but I'm worried that my examiner might not know it.
P.S my question is not about the meaning of the idiom

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+albatross+round+his+neck%2Can+albatross+around+his+neck&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20albatross%20round%20his%20neck%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20albatross%20around%20his%20neck%3B%2Cc0) would appear to constitute relevant research.

Comment: Did you try looking it up in a dictionary? Did you find it there? Was there a note saying it was archaic or obscure? If not, you should be fine. If your examiner doesn’t know it, so what? No one knows every word in the language, including your examiner.

Comment: It would strike me as rather affected if I were your evaluator and this was supposed to be spontaneous speech (I confess I don't know how the speaking part of the IELTS works). I would lightly suggest against using it.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai, can you explain why? Speaking part has 2 parts - a story (namely, Present) with questions given in a card and 3 mins preparation for it. Than answering to the examiner's questions regarding other theme (say, Sport; spontaneously). I could say, for instance, that I had to buy a present and had an albatros.... because of this and that.

Comment: @kuku It's just archaic-sounding (I've never heard it before, but was perfectly able to guess at the meaning correctly) and would sound like a phrase you memorized for the test rather than a modern idiom used fluently.  It sounds like something out of the New Yorker

Comment: @Azor-Ahai if the idiom is used appropriately it doesn't matter if it sounds memorized as long as it's used naturally. Examiners expect non-native candidates to not sound perfectly fluent or perfectly natural. Are you a native speaker? Because the poem, the Ancient Mariner, is (or used to be...?) extremely well-known in the UK. By the way, the OP heard it being used on the BBC, which is not the New Yorker, but the British state-run broadcasting organisation. I should think it knows whether its viewers or listeners are familiar with an idiom or not.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Which is why I "lightly" recommended against it. I don't know what IELTS examiners look for. And yes, I'm a native speaker. I am aware of the poem, but I wouldn't call it "extremely well-known" in the US, I didn't learn about it in either high school or undergrad, and I quite enjoyed my literature classes.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai you also said `It would strike me as rather affected if I were your evaluator` if used inappropriately it might well do, but if used well it might make a difference of 0.5 in the speaking. Might... all depends on how well the rest of the speaking test goes. Kuku it's the British equivalent of the American idiom or, if you prefer,  the forefather of [**a millstone around someone's neck**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/a_millstone_around_someone's_neck)

Comment: @kuku Do make sure you are using it idiomatically, something has to be identified **as** the albatross eg ‘X is/was [like] an albatross around my neck’ than that ‘I have/had an albatross around my neck because of X’.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This is why I left a comment rather than an answer. It would be odd in my dialect, maybe not so much in yours.  I think the context of where the OP heard it on the BBC might matter, was it in a speech in Parliament, or from a character on a sitcom? I don't know which register IELTS is expecting its testees to shoot for.

Comment: Specify what you mean by "*common modern usage*".

Comment: Only one data point so not enough for an answer but as an Australian native speaker I've *never* heard the term. 'White elephant' would be a more common alternative.

Comment: @WesToleman I'm not sure the phrases are precisely equivalent, since a white elephant rather implies a gift or similar external source, at least in British English.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai, I heard it on the political news\discussion

Answer (score 40):

This idiom is a reference to [The Rime of the Ancient Mariner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rime_of_the_Ancient_Mariner) in which the narrator shoots an albatros - a 'bird of ill omen' - and terrible consequences ensue.  The rest of the crew force him to wear the dead albatross round his neck in penance (actually, I always found this a bit strange - an albatross is a *big* bird!). 
Anyway, the idiom is taken to mean an unpleasant burden which one cannot escape. 
It's a moderately well-known idiom in English; you could use it in formal contexts, in my opinion.
Edit in the light of Lambie's comment: - It's not flippant, or offensive or humorous, hence my opinion ref formal contexts.

Comment: I upvote. Dunno about formal contexts. It would depend on your interlocutor.

Comment: @Lambie, it was deleted - this is for the IELTS exam, where I should use idioms as well

Comment: The meaning of the expression is general reference and not asked for. As to register and currency, unsupported opinion does not constitute an answer of the type expected on ELU.

Comment: ... and the only way to get rid of it is to persuade someone else to accept the burden.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it's the opinion of a native speaker which is useful and more helpful than a simple citation from a dictionary. I know of one native speaker who never cites a single reference, yet his answers are rarely criticised for lack of support (Obviously it's not you, but you do know him)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Published academics carry a certain degree of self-authentication. Especially emeritus professors. The Ngrams are surely more acceptable than the opinion of _a user who prefers to keep an air of mystery about themself_.

Comment: (+1) My heart skipped a beat when I saw this thread: *The Rime of the Ancyent Marinere* is my fav! I think it’s perfectly on point to identify this comment appropriate for formal contexts! Not only is *Rime* is an English classic, but it’s also a masterful work of rather dense literature. I would expect intelligent and/or well-read individuals to be familiar with it. In fact, I believe most native speakers of English who were educated in a Western cultural context should be familiar with Coleridge. (Whether they kept up with schoolwork or remembered what they learned is a different story.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sure Edwin, if the user wants to support his answer with graphs then, by all means, he should be encouraged, but peterG's answer is perfectly correct and appropriate nonetheless. Besides, the OP says he doesn't care about its meaning but whether native speakers and Cambridge examiners will have heard of the idiom. Well, the answerer is a native speaker and he hasn't copied and pasted his answer from the Internet, it's an honest and original answer. The best there is. Thumbs up!

Comment: P.S @EdwinAshworth actually I wasn't referring to the academician whose revered name shall not be mentioned but rather to (2) British users, whose English, and punctuation are always impeccable. I nearly always upvote their contributions because I trust them.

Comment: It is certainly in use; I've used it, my father used it, I've seen references to the albatross in numerous places and to really answer the important part of the question: if the examiner isn't familiar with it, being able to explain its origin will show his familiarity with both English language *and* culture, seems like a win-win. Caveat: if they go on to ask questions about other literature, it would be good if that weren't the only writer or poem that he were acquainted with! :o)

Comment: It would seem to me that explaining a reference goes a long way to "locating" it in a type of speech or speech register.The problem with this site is that not everything can have a supported opinion as to currency. Maybe when the robots take over.  I can also speak for myself, but I use literary references with interlocutors who can understand them, unless of course, I am looking to play at oneupmanship with those who should.

Comment: "[The book is] also a *masterful work of rather dense literature.* I would expect intelligent and/or well-read individuals to be familiar with it." Read between all the lines in that comment and there's the answer. **The tester had better be intelligent and well read of rather dense literature.** Personally, I can count all the people I've ever met like that on zero fingers.

Comment: This is a rather heavy analogy, so I'd avoid forcing it in to a conversation.  I expect most native speakers will be familiar with it even if they haven't read Coleridge.

Comment: Geeze, I wonder when school stop teaching *The Rime of the Ancient Mariner*. I absolutely studied it in school in the US in the 1960's. I'd guess it was somewhere about the time that keyboarding replaced typing and computer programming replaced learning a second language. ..sigh.. // Water water everywhere and all the boards did shrink, water water everywhere and not a drop to drink.

Comment: @MaxW ‘*nor any* drop to drink.‘ :)

Comment: @Spagirl [[The Yale Book of Quotations - Page 163](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=IDI6WvaUK8magAbSiZOAAg&q=Water+water+everywhere+and+all+the+boards+did+shrink%2C+water+water+%22everywhere+and+not+a+drop+to+drink%22&oq=Water+water+everywhere+and+all+the+boards+did+shrink%2C+water+water+%22everywhere+and+not+a+drop+to+drink%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21002.31897.0.32373.3.3.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.ernk_dmh...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.YQ-i-7I5uvE)] adds '... Popularly quoted as "Water, water, everywhere, and not a drop to drink." ' Are modern revisions unacceptable per se?

Comment: @kuku Are you sure that the IELTS specification is 'candidates should use idioms' or the like rather than 'candidates should use idiomatic English'? There is a large difference (which has been covered on ELU before); one must take the primary senses of 'idiom' and 'idiomatic', which do not correspond at all closely.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In my experience ‘water water everywhere and not a drop to drink’ is often used as a stand alone phrase eg it’s raining and you’d rather be in the pub or something. I’ve no issue with that. MaxW was quoting the *poem*, bewailing the lack of teaching of it but getting his quote wrong. I was aiming to help, hence the :). :)

Comment: The strangeness of the mariner being forced to wear the large bird isn't as strange as the taboo in the first place, since mariners in Coleridge's time and indeed for long before and quite a while since had no qualms about eating albatross if given the chance.

Comment: @Spagirl - Thanks for the correction. My 50 year old memory of the poem was only close, and close is only good in horseshoes. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It would certainly impress the average educated Brit, but if you are not sure of its usage then use something else. If you suspect your examiner would only be puzzled by it, then stay clear.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of one reference in (not so) popular music. Public Image Ltd's "Metal Box" / "Second Edition" features the 9-minute song "Albatross", in which John Lydon intones "Getting rid of the Albatross" as a sort of chorus. The Albatross in this case refers to the legacy of Lydon's former group The Sex Pistols, which he was distancing himself from, and which he perceived to be an artistic burden.

Answer (score 2):

The albatross around one’s neck as a symbol of endless, self-inflicted bad luck comes from “The Rime of the Ancient Marineer” by Samuel Taylor Coleridge. The poem is a fairly common assignment in high-school English classes, at least in my experience. I went to high school in New York City; we had to memorize stanzas of it as punishment if we forgot our materials for class. I had a number of friends who attended other schools, and were also required to read it. Can’t say it was a *popular* assignment (as I said, for my class it was literally punishment), but it did get read.

On the other hand, it wasn’t a particularly popular assignment, and I suspect its tendency to stick out in many people’s minds stems mostly from its considerable length. For anyone who either didn’t pay enough attention in the first place, or wasn’t particularly struck by the poem (and/or by its length) to remember it, or simply didn’t happen to have it assigned in the first place, the phrase is probably unknown. It is not a widely used phrase, in either conversation or media.

But as some evidence that it is widely-known *enough* to see use, the film *Serenity* includes this dialogue:

> The Operative: That girl will rain destruction down on you and your ship. She is an albatross, Captain.
>
> Capt. Malcolm Reynolds: Way I remember it, albatross was a ship’s good luck, ’til some idiot killed it.
>
> Capt. Malcolm Reynolds: [to Inara] Yes, I’ve read a poem. Try not to faint.

and then later, to the “that girl” in question:

> Capt. Malcolm Reynolds: But it ain’t all buttons and charts, little albatross.

*Serenity* was a feature-length major motion picture from 2005; the people who made it apparently considered their audience likely enough to know of “The Rime of the Ancient Marineer” and its albatross to include these lines (but then also basically explained the reference with the “Yes, I’ve read a poem,” line).

Comment: recent "albatross sighting" in discussion of a controversial figure in US politics in a CNN news video: [As it is, however, I think both rightly suggest (politician's name) has become an albatross around the neck of the (political party).](https://youtu.be/puJgzOPga_M?t=198)